# UCanAccess exception "Unsupported newer version: 5"

Tags: java, maven, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I'm trying to access MS Access 2016 (.accdb) file using ucanaccess(4.0.2) jar with the code:

```
public class Test {
    static String path ="*****/src/main/resources/TestDatabase.accdb";  //absolute path to my access file
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
       Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+path);
}
```

I'm getting the below exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.2 Unsupported newer version: 5
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:264)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
at db.Test.main(Test.java:29)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unsupported newer version: 5
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.JetFormat.getFormat(JetFormat.java:293)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.<init>(DatabaseImpl.java:517)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.open(DatabaseImpl.java:400)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(DatabaseBuilder.java:252)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DefaultJackcessOpener.open(DefaultJackcessOpener.java:35)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReference.<init>(DBReference.java:161)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReferenceSingleton.loadReference(DBReferenceSingleton.java:51)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:98)
... 3 more
```

Maven Dependencies used :

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `Unsupported newer version: 5` you really don't know what that could mean?

Comment: Surprisingly while UCanAccess declares support of access 2016 the underlying Jackcess library doesn't. This is an exception from Jackcess about unsupported version. Not sure why a mismatch. Check UCanAccess documentation related to 2016 release. Maybe something there. You may try overriding to latest Jackcess 2.1.9 manually but I have doubts that this will help.

Comment: I'm not that experienced with UCanAccess, but have experienced similar issues with ODBC and databases using the `BigInt` data type. See [this Microsoft support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3208802/-database-you-are-trying-to-open-requires-a-newer-version-of-microsoft) (BigInt is a really new data type that has been implemented only in newer versions of Access 2016, I doubt UCanAccess has implemented it already)

Comment: @aleh you are right, I digged into the code and found that the jet engine used in MS Access 2016 isn't yet supported by the jackcess2.1.6 library which is used by ucanaccess jar. I'll try to override  the jackacess 2.1.6 with it's newest version.

Answer (score 1):

Jackcess will support Access 2016 databases in the 2.1.10 release (changes are currently in trunk, but not yet released).

Answer (score 0):

1. Override your Library with the latest jar file from [jackcess](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jackcess/files/jackcess/)
2. Go to your MS Access 2016
3. Under "Info" click "[Compact and Repair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0wx8.png)". Save the table.
4. Try running the netbeans code again.

It worked in my case :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same error. I've upgraded to jackcess-3.0.1 and it is solved now.