# How to solve UCanAcess "Unsupported newer Version: 51"-Error

Tags: java, maven, ms-access, ucanaccess, jackcess

I have a mdb-file which I want to read through Java. For that I imported the dependencies through maven.I have the ojdbc8 lib (version 18.3.0.0), the ucanaccess lib (version 5.0.0) and after I read that the jackcess version should be up to date I manually set the jackcess lib to 3.5.0.

```xml
<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>Access-DB</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>18.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ucanaccess</groupId>
        <artifactId>ucanaccess</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.healthmarketscience.jackcess</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackcess</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But I still get the Unsupported newer Version-Error:

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::5.0.0 Unsupported newer version: 51
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:231)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
at main.java.AccessDB.main(AccessDB.java:14)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unsupported newer version: 51
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.JetFormat.getFormat(JetFormat.java:310)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.<init>(DatabaseImpl.java:538)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.open(DatabaseImpl.java:415)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(DatabaseBuilder.java:267)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DefaultJackcessOpener.open(DefaultJackcessOpener.java:37)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReference.<init>(DBReference.java:170)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReferenceSingleton.loadReference(DBReferenceSingleton.java:51)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:91)
... 3 more
```

The script I use to read the Access file looks like this:

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class AccessDBConnection {
    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        try {
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://access/remote.mdb");
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from summary_0199_550");


            System.err.println("asdasda");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }

        } catch ( Exception ee) {
            ee.printStackTrace();
            //System.out.println(ee);
        }

    }
}
```

The libraries are all there:

[image]

Comment: What would happen when you add "1.8" to maven.compiler.target and maven.compiler.source in your pom.xml?

Comment: Thats exactly how my pom.xml looks like, I just added the dependencies.
I should edit my post

Comment: Does [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46803010/ucanaccess-exception-unsupported-newer-version-5) help? Seems worth trying 'compact and repair' operation on your database file.

Comment: @MNEMO No it didn't help unfortunately... I think the problem is that these files are MS Access 95 files, that are not supported by UCanAccess as saw in the documentation. But how am I supposed to read these files then?

Comment: Access 95 is too old... there might be some converters to much more modern version files, but I don't know details (just tried some internet search), so I am sorry that I cannot help further.

Comment: use a newer version of access to "compact and repair" the files and upgrade to a newer version (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-access-2-0-and-access-95-databases-into-current-versions-2e9d8851-101d-4407-a881-65d06bb12aa7)